# Directory Download Link not working "Server Error 404 - File or directory not found."

Tags: php, html

I am working on an Intranet with a searchable document repository page. It uses some php to generate a list of documents in a directory and put them in a table. When I click the link in the second column it should download the document but instead shows an error page with the phrase "404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

I'm using Windows server 2012 r2 and ISS 7.5.

I double checked and the files are definitely in the correct directory.

Here's the code for the webpage.

```
<?php
function getFileList($dir)
{
  $retVal = array();
if (substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // open pointer to directory and read list of files
    $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for     reading");

        while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
        // skip hidden files
        if($entry[0] == ".") continue;

            if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
                $filename = "$dir$entry";
                $retval[] = array(
                "title" => "$filename/",
                "path" => filetype("$filename"),
                "size" => 0,
                "lastmod" => filemtime("$filename"));
            } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) { 
                $filename = "$dir$entry";
                $retval[] = array(
                "title" => "$entry",
                "path" => "$filename",
                "size" => filesize("$filename"),
                "lastmod" => filemtime("$filename"));

            }
        }

    $d->close();

return $retval;

}
?>

<?php
    $dirlist = getFileList("docs");
    print "<table id='myTable' border=\"1\">\n";
    print "<thead>\n";
    print "<tr class='header'><th>File Name</th><th>Link (click to download)</th><th>Size</th><th>Last Modified</th></tr>\n";
    print "</thead>\n";
    print "<tbody>\n";
        foreach($dirlist as $file) {
            print "<tr>\n";
            print "<td>{$file['title']}</td>\n";
            $path_parts = pathinfo($file['path']);
            $path_noext = $path_parts['dirname'] . "/" . $path_parts['filename'];
            $path_noext = str_replace(' ', '%20', $path_noext);
            print "<td><a href=pdf_download.php?filename={$path_noext}>{$file['title']}</a></td>\n";
            print "<td>{$file['size']}</td>\n";
            $timestamp = date('F d Y h:i A', $file['lastmod']);
            print "<td>{$timestamp}</td>\n";
            print "</tr>\n";
        }   
  print "</tbody>";
  print "</table>";
 ?>
```

Comment: You sure there is a page called `pdf_download.php` inside the current directory?

Comment: Is the `pdf_download.php` script in the same directory as the script that generates the file listing?

Comment: @PeterM I found this code online and didn't even notice that until now! Unfortunately where I got this code from they don't mention any pdf_download.php file. I'm not sure if maybe they left something out or if it's just a place holder.

Comment: That's your problem then, try removing that part of the URL

Comment: Good news and bad news. Removing that part of the URL stopped me from going to the 404 page, but now when clicked the page just reloads.

Comment: Did you also remove the part that says `?filename=` ?

Comment: Can you share the code you have on pdf_download.php file?

Comment: @PeterM I removed that as well and now it gives the 404 page again.

Comment: @HSharma I edited my post to include the HTML, php, css, and javascript I used. When run in code snippet it won't recognize/run the php though.

Comment: @jacobmcdowell Well if you can share the php code it will be great coz I did similar thing recently and will be able to review code and guide you accordingly. Just need to see the code where you are getting the filename and forcing download.

Comment: @HSharma The php is inside the HTML. Is there another way you'd like me to share it?

Comment: @jacobmcdowell just copy n paste here

Comment: @HSharma It's too long to paste in the comments.

Comment: @jacobmcdowell just edit your initial question and add it there

Comment: @HSharma I edited the initial question. It's just the php now.

Comment: @jacobmcdowell Well what I wanted to check is what exactly are you doing on pdf_download.php file where you are sending the filename parameter for download. The php code above is for reading the directory and listing the files. There must be file named pdf_download.php in your folder that is doing the download part.

Comment: @HSharma That's where the people above found the snag. I got the code online and the original publisher didn't give any pdf_download.php. I couldn't figure out what I need to do to make the links downloadable and hoped someone else might. Right now I guess i'm sending them nowhere.

Comment: @jacobmcdowell In that case create a file with that name in the same folder and you can add something like this in that file: $file_name = $_GET['filename'];
$filePath = $dir.'/'.$file_name;
if(!empty($file_name) && file_exists($filePath)){
 // Define headers
 header("Cache-Control: public");
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
 header("Content-Type: application/zip");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 // Read the file
 readfile($filePath);
 exit;
}else{
 echo 'The file does not exist.';
}

Comment: @HSharma I've added that in a new document and now it links me to a blank page. Also, my sincere apologies for being difficult to work with on this subject, I know almost no php, only HTML and CSS.

Comment: @jacobmcdowell did you change $dir with your directory path?

Comment: @HSharma Yes, the line reads $filePath = $dir.'docs'.$file_name;

Comment: @jacobmcdowell well it should be something like:

$filePath = "C:\xampp\htdocs\".$file_name;

so $dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\'  <--- this will be the path to your directory where files exist

Comment: @HSharma it still directs to a blank page

Comment: @jacobmcdowell please share the path you are using for $filePath = $dir.'/'.$file_name;

Comment: @HSharma $filePath = $dir.'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Intranet\DocRepo3.0\docs'.$file_name;

Comment: @jacobmcdowell It should be $filePath = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Intranet\DocRepo3.0\docs\'.$file_nam‌​e;

Comment: @HSharma that still provides a blank page.

Comment: @jacobmcdowell can you share the code for just this page here in the comment, just want to make sure you got that right

Comment: @HSharma <?
$file_name = $_GET['filename']; 
$filePath = $dir.'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Intranet\DocRepo3.0\docs\'.$file_name; 
if(!empty($file_name) && file_exists($filePath))
{ // Define headers header("Cache-Control: public"); 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name"); 
header("Content-Type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
// Read the file readfile($filePath); 
exit; }else{ echo 'The file does not exist.'; }
?>

Comment: Use this   <?php 

$file_name = $_GET['filename']; 
$filePath = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Intranet\DocRepo3.0\docs\'.$file_na‌​me; 

// Define headers header("Cache-Control: public"); 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name"); 
header("Content-Type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
// Read the file readfile($filePath); 
exit; 

?>

Comment: @HSharma It now redirects to a page that says "The eagle.fnba.com page isn't working".

Comment: @jacobmcdowell add couple of .txt files in the docs folder and try to download them from the listings page, if they are working fine then it's all good.

Comment: @HSharma still no good with the .txt files

Comment: @jacobmcdowell any errors?

Comment: @HSharma same page not working error as before

Comment: @HSharma I finally found a solution, thank you very much for your help I don't think I would have found an answer without you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

Change this line:

```
print "<td><a href=pdf_download.php?filename={$path_noext}>{$file['title']}</a></td>\n";
```

To this:

```
print "<td><a href=docs/{$file['title']}>{$file['title']}</a></td>\n";
```

It couldn't find the files because the download link was pointed to the root directory not to the documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
print "<td><a href=pdf_download.php?filename={$path_noext}>{$file['title']}</a></td>\n";
```

Into

```
print "<td><a href=\"pdf_download.php?filename={$path_noext}\">{$file['title']}</a></td>\n";
```

You didn't quote the actual `href` part of the link.

Comment: Since there's no space in the filename, why would this help?

Comment: However, it's always a good idea to put quotes around HTML attributes.

Comment: Though you are right we do not know the contents of either `$path_noext` or `$file['title']` there could easily be a space in there.